# Other days of the week - Birthday Paradox

Tags: probability, paradoxes, birthday

I'm trying to solve a birthday paradox problem, I'm really close to the answer but I guess I'm doing something wrong. The problem states that the probability of being born on a friday is $\frac{1}{3}$ and is equally probable to any other day of the week. Assuming 4 (or any number n people) where selected, what is the probability to have for example two born on friday and two born on other days of the week?

I know that the probability of two people sharing the same birthday is:
$$\frac{(365*364*363*362)}{365^n}$$
Another note I was able to come to is that the chance of last two not sharing birthdays with the first two is:
$$1-\frac{5}{7}*\frac{4}{7} \approx 0.591$$

> Assuming that a person can be born on a Friday with probability 1/3
>   and with equal probability any other day of the week. What is the
>   probability that among 4 randomly selected people, two were born on
>   the same day and the other two in two other days?

The correct answer according to my exercise sheet is about $0.52$.
Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: The people's _actual_ birthdays are irrelevant, so your first probability is moot to the problem.  Just think of it in terms of days of the week; you need to have two people on Friday - and the probability of someone being born on Friday is 1/7 - and two people born on other days of the week (what's the probability of that?).  You then need to consider all the different _combinations_ of two people that could be born on Friday.

Comment: (That said, 0.52 is definitely not the probability that two were born on Friday and two on other days; can you be more specific/more precise about the statement of the problem?)

Comment: Oh wait... are the people distinct or not? My answer assumed that they were distinct people.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki I added the original problem to the post

Comment: @Nilknarf I updated the OP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is of course unrealistic that the chance of a person born on a Friday is $\frac{1}{3}$, but so be it.  We are also told that for all other days of the week the chance is the same, so that would be

$$\frac{1-\frac{1}{3}}{6}=\frac{1}{9}$$ (e.g. the chance of being born on a Wednesday is $\frac{1}{9}$)

Now, there are various ways to have 2 people being born on the same day, and the other two on 2 other days:

$A$. Two born on a Friday, and the other two on two different days other than Friday

$B$. Two born on the same day but other than a Friday, one born on Friday, and the last on a different day yet.

$C$. Two born on the same day but other than a Friday, and the other two on two different days other than Friday

$$P(A) = {4 \choose 2} \cdot \big( \frac{1}{3} \big)^2\cdot \frac{6}{9} \cdot \frac{5}{9} = \frac{180}{729}$$

(the $4 \choose 2$ is the number of ways to pick the two people born on a Friday)

$$P(B) = {4 \choose 2} \cdot 6 \cdot \big( \frac{1}{9} \big)^2\cdot 2 \cdot \frac{1}{3} \cdot \frac{5}{9} = \frac{120}{729}$$

(the extra $2$ term is to distinguish the two people: one born on Friday, the other not. The $6$ is to pick one of the 6 days that the first two are born on)

$$P(C) = {4 \choose 2} \cdot 6 \cdot \big( \frac{1}{9} \big)^2 \cdot \frac{5}{9} \cdot \frac{4}{9} = \frac{80}{729}$$

Hence, the chance that 2 people being born on the same day, and the other two on 2 other days is:

$$P(A)+P(B)+P(C)=\frac{380}{729} \approx 0.52$$

Comment: Thank you for your input, I do agree the probability $1/3$ is unrealistic.

Comment: Thank you for your input, I do agree the probability $1/3$ is unrealistic but I guess the goal as to steer us

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should not involve number of days in a year, because there is no assumption about uniform distribution on each days of a year.

In fact, since the assumption is evenly distributed across a week, it is slightly not evenly distributed across days in a year

$$\frac{\binom{4}{2} \times 1 \times 1 \times 6 \times 6}{7^4}$$

**EDIT according to OP's edit**

Notice that Friday has a different probability than other days.

$$\binom{4}{2}\times \frac{1}{3}\times \frac{1}{3} \times \frac{6}{9} \times \frac{5}{9} $$
$$+ \binom{4}{2} \times \binom{7-1}{1} \times \frac{1}{9} \times \frac{1}{9} \times \binom{2}{1} \times \frac{1}{3} \times \frac{5}{9}$$
$$+\binom{4}{2} \times \binom{7-1}{1} \times \frac{1}{9} \times \frac{1}{9} \times \frac{5}{9} \times \frac{4}{9}$$

Comment: Thank you for your input I think I didn't explain the problem well, would you mind please having another look at the OP?

Comment: Sorry just get chance to check your edit - I saw there is an answer already, but I'll update mine anyway.